# ALTER DATABASE AUDIT produces a syntax error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to ADD CREATE and DROP commands to an existing SERVER AUDIT.

When executing the following statement :

```
ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION Powercash_Audit
    FOR SERVER AUDIT PowercashAudit
    ADD (CREATE, DROP ON SCHEMA::dbo BY PUBLIC)
    WITH (STATE = ON);
GO
```

I've got the following error :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE'."
```

I didn't fix it yet, any ideas ?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: I don't think you can add an audit for `CREATE` and `DROP`

Comment: I think you misunderstand what that command does, see the syntax page here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-server-audit-specification-transact-sql

Comment: The audit groups available is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, the `CREATE` and `DROP` actions cannot be directly added to a server-level audit specification. These actions are only applicable at the database level. Therefore, you need to modify your script to create a database-level audit specification and associate it with the desired server-level audit.

```sql
USE [YourDatabaseName];
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION Powercash_Audit
    FOR SERVER AUDIT PowercashAudit
    ADD (SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP)

USE [YourDatabaseName];
ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION Powercash_Audit
    ADD (CREATE, DROP ON SCHEMA::dbo BY PUBLIC)
    WITH (STATE = ON);
```